# mysql query: how to

Tags: mysql, database

here's my (simplified) table structure:

```
table: category_main
id  name
-------------
1   food
2   vegetable

table category_sub
id  id_catmain  name 
---------------------
10  1           cake
11  1           chocolate 
12  1           burger
13  2           apple
14  2           banana

table images
id  id_catsub filename         views
-------------------------------------
 1  10        cake1.jpg        11
 2  10        cake2.jpg        24 
 3  10        cake3.jpg        65
 4  11        chocolate1.jpg   31
 5  11        chocolate2.jpg   62
 6  11        chocolate3.jpg   32
 7  11        chocolate4.jpg   58
 8  12        burger1.jpg      23
 9  12        burger2.jpg      43 
10  12        burger3.jpg      76
11  13        apple1.jpg       29
11  13        apple2.jpg       67
11  14        banana1.jpg      78
```

desired output:

```
id  name        total_views
----------------------------
1   food        425 
2   vegetable   174
```

as you can see i want to get the total views for each main category.
currently i'm running a loop for each subcategory but there must be an easier and faster way :/

thanks

Comment: Look into `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double `LEFT JOIN` + aggregation will do the job.

```
SELECT cm.id, cm.name, sum(images.views) as views
FROM category_main as cm
LEFT JOIN category_sub as cs ON cs.id_catmain = cm.id
LEFT JOIN images ON images.id_carsub = cs.id
GROUP BY cm.id
ORDER BY views DESC;
```

`LEFT JOIN` (instead of `JOIN`) will make you sure that you have all categories listed even if there's no subcategory or image in it. If you don't want empty categories to be listed, then use `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.id AS id, c.name AS name, sum(i.views) AS total_views
FROM category_main c, category_sub s, images i
WHERE c.id=s.id_catmain and s.id=i.id_catsub
GROUP BY c.id,c.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

simply join the three tables, and then you can sum the views grouped by the id's:

```
select cm.id, cm.name, sum(i.views) as total_views from
category_main as cm inner join category_sub as cs on cm.id = cs.id_catmain
inner join cs.id = i.id_catsub group by cm.id
```